Spring Boot check isHttpOnly cookie not working
I'm storing my authentication token on an http-only cookie. When an user logs-in, an http cookie carrying the token will be set. Here's the code to process the login:
@PostMapping("/processlogin")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> processLogin(
    @RequestBody SigninDataDto signinDataDto,
    HttpServletResponse response
) {
    if(signinDataDto.getUserName()!=null && signinDataDto.getPassword()!=null) {
        String userName = signinDataDto.getUserName();
        String password = Common.sha256Hash(signinDataDto.getPassword());
        boolean rememberMe = signinDataDto.isRememberMe();
        UserDetails customUserDetails = new UserService(userRepository).loadUserByUsername(userName);
        if(password.equals(customUserDetails.getPassword())) {
            //Authenticate by cookie
            Cookie jwtCookie = new Cookie(Constants.JWT_NAME, jwtService.generateToken((CustomUserDetails) customUserDetails));
            if(rememberMe) {
                jwtCookie.setMaxAge(7*24*60*60);
            }
            jwtCookie.setPath("/");
            jwtCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            response.addCookie(jwtCookie);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("success");
        }
    }
    log.error("Login failed!");
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("failed");
}

Then i made a filter to authenticate each request by getting the token cookie and verify it. Here's the filter code:
package com.springdemo.library.security;

import com.springdemo.library.services.JwtService;
import com.springdemo.library.services.UserService;
import com.springdemo.library.utils.Common;
import com.springdemo.library.utils.Constants;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService customUserDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwt(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtService.validateToken(jwt)) {
                String userName = jwtService.getUserNameFromJWT(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
                if(userDetails != null) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,
                            userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                } else {
                    response.sendRedirect("/login");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("failed on set user authentication", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = Common.getCookie(request, Constants.JWT_NAME);
        if(cookie!=null) {
            String token = cookie.getValue();
            if(StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
                return token;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Security config:
@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests
                            .requestMatchers("/login", "/processlogin").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}

It works fine if in the filter I don't check isHttpOnly for the jwt cookie, but if I do, the browser denies access to /Library/home. Please can anyone explain why can't the filter verify isHttpOnly for the jwt cookie, eventhough I set the cookie as HttpOnly? And any way to check if a cookie is HttpOnly in Java/Spring Boot?
Here's the JavaScript code that I used to login
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#id-form-login').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Library/processlogin',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                userName: $("#login-username").val(),
                password: $("#login-password").val(),
                rememberMe: $("#rememberme").prop("checked")
            }),
            success: function () {
                window.location.replace("/Library/home");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.warn('Error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});

Appreciate anyone who helps

Can you please explain what you actually mean by, "It works fine if in the filter I don't check isHttpOnly for the jwt cookie" - what "check" are you referring to here?

I mean i want to check if the cookie is httponly, if it's not, the request is denied.

You can not "check" that for a cookie that you receive from the client. All you get is the name=value pair, all other "options" used when the cookie was set, will not get send back to the server.

I see, thanks for your explaination
